# In JS, get actual (computed) stroke-width of SVG path

Tags: javascript, css, svg

Given a DOM node of an SVG path element, how would I get the `stroke-width` of that path in units of its parent element?  The goal is to add "decorations" to the path by adding additional elements to the parent of the path, whose dimensions are determined proportional to the path's `stroke-width`. The `stroke-width` of the path may be determined via CSS, inline styles or whatever else might influence the stroke.

I know that I can get the computed style value `window.getComputedStyle(node)['stroke-width']`. but that returns a string with including units.

In what coordinate system do these units apply? Can I assume that the units will always be `px` and thus simply strip the last two characters to get to a number?

Comment: They are user units i.e. in the local co-ordinate system for the element.

Comment: Thanks @RobertLongson, that is an important aspect! Is there a reference which can confirm that?

Comment: You mean besides someone who's written a large chunk of the SVG implementation in Firefox telling you? How about you read [the SVG specification section then](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#Units).

Comment: @RobertLongson: '...can confirm that' was not well written, sorry! I didn't mean to disqualify your statement. I was looking for a specification pointer where I could go to when something doesn't add up and I need to rule out edge cases (i.e. the browser doesn't implement it correctly: if I have a section number of a specification, it's easier to read browser conformance charts). I have read that part of the spec before and know about user units. I didn't go there immediately, as _computed style_ is a user-agent feature, not a SVG feature.

Comment: In particular, the SVG spec states that all lengths are "user units" in the local coordinate system, and how a user agent has to scale absolute units into user units. It still doesn't guarantee that the user agent gives the computed style back as a length in user units/px, and if doesn't choose px, how I'd query the user agent what scaling factor it employs (which, according to the spec, it determines from it's environment).

Answer (score -1):

According to [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle#Notes) `getComputedStyle()` returns so called [computed values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/computed_value) for most of properties and it is defined into `px`. So you can try to do something like:

```
var value = window.getComputedStyle(node)['stroke-width'];
if (value.match(/^\-?\d+(\.\d+)px$/)) {
  value = parseFloat(value.substr(-2));
} else {
  // Examine value further
}
```

I've used `parseFloat` instead of `parseInt` because it may be possible that computed value is fractional of original value is defined into non-px units.

Comment: This one will give you actual value, not a computed one.